# silex 2.0.4 and symfony form 3.2

Tags: symfony-forms, silex

I'm trying to use Symfony form 3.2 with Silex 2.0.4.

After upgrading, I got the following issue:

`Passing a Twig Form Renderer to the "Symfony\Bridge\Twig\Extension\FormExtension" constructor is deprecated since version 3.2 and won't be possible in 4.0. Pass the Twig_Environment to the TwigRendererEngine constructor instead.`

Answer (score 0):

The issue comes from Silex\Provider\TwigServiceProvider.

I managed the issue by overriding TwigServiceProvider and change:

`$twig->addExtension(new FormExtension($app['twig.form.renderer']));`

into

`$twig->addExtension(new FormExtension());`

Is it the best way?

**Edit**: it was an issue with Silex 2.x. versions >= 2.1.0 should be fixed (https://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.0/changelog.html)

`fixed deprecation notices with symfony/twig-bridge 3.2+ in TwigServiceProvider`